# Select Unique rows from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

We have 3 tables in MySQL database,

**Industries Table**

**industries**

```
| pkIndustryID | industryName           |
|--------------|------------------------|
| 1            | Accounting and Finance |
| 2            | Legal                  |
| 3            | Health Care            |
```

**User table**

**users**

```
| pkUserID | UserName         |
|----------|------------------|
| 1        | Saurabh Sharma   |
| 2        | Avinash Panday   |
| 3        | Mrinal Chaudahry |
```

**Relationship table for user and industry**

**provider_industries**

```
| pkProviderindustryID | fkUserID | fkIndustryID |
|----------------------|----------|--------------|
| 1                    | 1        | 1            |
| 2                    | 1        | 2            |
| 3                    | 2        | 1            |
| 4                    | 2        | 2            |
| 5                    | 3        | 1            |
| 6                    | 3        | 2            |
| 7                    | 3        | 3            |
```

Now my question is i want users from all insutries but any user should not be repeated . How to achieve this with single SQL query ?

**Expected Result is**

```
| pkProviderindustryID | fkUserID | fkIndustryID |
|----------------------|----------|--------------|
| 1                    | 1        | 1            |
| 4                    | 2        | 2            |
| 7                    | 3        | 3            |
```

I don't want the user and industries to be repeated !
Result should show distinct user with distinct industry. InsustryID or userID any of them should not be repeated

Any help will be appreciated !!!
Thanks !!!

Comment: Add the expected result as well!

Comment: What have you tried so far? How many queries did you use to achieve this? Please, insert your code so people can help you based on it.

Comment: @jarlh Expected result added

Comment: @Tom I have tried left join but i am getting redundant results from that

Comment: There's no problem with the query and its problems @SaurabhSrb. Post it in the question and say the error you're getting. It will make it faster to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select p.pkProviderindustryID, u.fkUserID, i.fkIndustryID 
from industries i 
join provider_industries p on i.pkIndustryID =p.fkIndustryID  
join users u on p.fkUserID = u.pkUserID 
group by u.pkUserID
```

Comment: @Tom in this , industry ID is repeated

Answer (score 0):

just group by your users

ie:

```
select users.pkUserID, users.UserName 
  from provider_industries
     inner join users
        on users.pkUserID = provider_industries.fkUserID 
  group by users.pkUserID, users.UserName
```

If you wanted to add the industry you would need to use min() / max() 
eg

```
select users.pkUserID, users.UserName, min(industryName)
  from provider_industries
     inner join users
        on users.pkUserID = provider_industries.fkUserID 
      inner join industries
        on industries.pkIndustryID = provider_industries.pkProviderindustryID
  group by users.pkUserID, users.UserName
```

Comment: started writing this before I saw the expected result

Comment: When you specify 2 parameters in group by, results got increased